# Move an image when hovering with jquery

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to get the two icons on the left to move to the left when hovering. Can anyone tell me why it's not working? here's the fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/JLfvz/ 
     here's the HTML

```
<div id="socials">
  <a href="http://twitter.com/" title="Twitter" class="social"><img     src="http://www.dot.state.oh.us/groups/ohol/PublishingImages/twitter-icon.gif"  alt="Twitter"></a>
  <a href="http://facebook.com/" title="Facebook"><img src="images/fb.png" alt="Facebook"></a><br>
  <a href="http://youtube.com" title="You Tube" class="social"><img src="https://encrypted-tbn3.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRvpJGY5jiR_SO4Hp2d6unwHcR3J-2vHxYOQ_-rVs8ZxUW8Mn5T6UNI1i0L" alt="youtube"></a>
  <a href="http://linkdin.com" title="Linkd In"><img src="images/in.png" alt="linkdin"></a>

  </div>
```

Comment: Post your code in your question and don't attempt to sidestep the SO rule of doing so when linking to jsFiddle.

Answer (score 1):

You need to update the css on the child `img` element, not the top-level `a.social` element:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".social").hover(function(){
        $(this).children().css("left","0");
    },function(){
        $(this).children().css("left","30px");
    });
});
```

Updated demo: http://jsfiddle.net/JLfvz/2/